# Most Efficient way to access schema with ODBC and OleDB

Tags: schema, odbc, oledb

I am making a DAL template with C# and I am wondering what is the most efficient way to access schema information with ODBC and OleDB. I need the columns, column types, and primary key information.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For OleDb, there is an OleDbConnection.GetoleDbSchemaTable() method. I've used it with Access.

I have an example in this code on GitHub:
[SchemaValidator.cs](http://github.com/rally25rs/storm/blob/053947d25ab5d789bf3f33302cf3e4aaf4ea08bf/StormOleDbSupport/DataBinders/OleDb/Validation/SchemaValidator.cs)

There should be a .Schema() method on OdbcConnection too IIRC.

I have noticed that the actual returned values may vary by database, so you'll want to do a fair amount of checking and debugging to see what he returned values may be.

Answer (score 0):

Use the SQL Server Management Objects:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx

for example:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server s = new 
        Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server( @"DUFF\SQLEXPRESS" );

foreach ( Database db in s.Databases )
{
    if ( ! db.IsSystemObject )
    {
        listboxDatabase.Items.Add( db.Name );
    }
}
```

from here, you can get the tables in the database (and other objects).

Comment: I don't think smo works with ODBC and OleDB. Doesn't it only work with SqlServer?

Comment: SQL Server Express is cheaper than MS Access.

Comment: john.strez--ah... you are right. I've been heads down on SMO and didn't the forest for the trees.